# how to filter a select statement in mysql for a particular time period without using now()

Tags: mysql, date

I have tried to filter records but with the use of now function as given below

```
 select * from table where date>= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) ,INTERVAL 90 DAY )
```

What I need is a select statement that can filter its records for a week or month from the current date but without using `NOW()` function

Comment: What is your proposal for getting the current date?  Do you want it hardcoded?  Can `CURDATE()` be used?

Comment: i am not using now because i have read that if i use now() then mysql queries wont be cached so curdate() cannot be used as well its given here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-operation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using java you could make use of the following code

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

or you could use curdate() of mysql

Comment: I'm upvoting, because you seem to have a remarkable ability to read the minds of people asking questions.  I don't want to know how you figured out that java was the right solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since I found it hard to understand the question I provide the following possibilities:

Try for all dates in *a week from now*:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

and for all dates in *a month from now*:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

If you are looking for all dates of the *current month* use

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE MONTH(date)=MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date)=YEAR(CURDATE())
```

or for all dates of the *current week* use

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE WEEK(date)=WEEK(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date)=YEAR(CURDATE())
```